# Data binding to objects which are initially null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a Camera object which has properties like Name, SensorWidth, SensorHeight etc. I would like to bind these properties to UI, but Camera is null at the time application starts (user can select any camera). Only when camera is opened, Camera object is initialized (and loads all its properties).

Is there a way to setup data binding in XAML so it starts to work when object is initialized?

I can do this easily in C# - setup data binding after camera is opened but this would had to be done in View code behind, which is probably bad for MVVM pattern I am using, since the button for opening camera is using Command interface to communicate with ViewModel.

What is the way to correctly approach this?

Comment: WPF data binding has no problem with any property in a property path being null. You may declare a Camera property that is initially null and bind like `{Binding Camera.Name}`. You only have to make sure that the Camera property fires a change notification.

Comment: You are right of course I missed the event in the Camera property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to setup data binding in XAML so it starts to work when object is initialized?

Bindings are designed to handle null values gracefully.  There should be no problem if your `Camera` object is null at startup.  WPF expects that the binding source might be null, and that any values along the property path might be null.

That said, it is useful to understand when a `Binding` produces a value successfully:

1. The path to the binding source resolves successfully.
2. The value converter, if any, is able to convert the resulting value.
3. The resulting value is valid for the binding target (target) property.

If (1) and (2) fail to produce a valid value, the binding will produce the default value of the target property.  If you want to specify an *alterate* value to use in this situation, you can provide a `FallbackValue` on your binding.

In your case, if you have `{Binding Camera.Name}`, and `Camera` is null, the binding will fail to produce a value.  If you changed the binding to `{Binding Camera.Name, FallbackValue='n/a'}`, then it produce the string `n/a` when `Camera` is null.

`TargetNullValue` lets you specify an alternate value in cases where the binding *does* produce a valid value, but that value is null.  For example, if `Camera` itself is *non-null*, but its `Name` is null, then `{Binding Camera.Name, TargetNullValue='(no name)'}` will produce the string `(no name)`.